# Access parts of large dataset without importing full set

Tags: data, memory

I have a massive, (mostly) static dataset as an [`Association`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) that I want to be able to access parts of without importing the whole thing as that's slow and eats up my memory. Is there a convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly what the [`"WDX"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/WDX.html) format appears to have been built for. Even if [WDX's days are numbered](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87355/38205) it's still a good tool for this job, as Mathematica supports it natively and it's, overall, reasonably efficient.

We'll take advantage of the `"DataTable"` format for WDX as detailed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/146139/38205) and I'll just provide some read sugar for it.

First we generate our "big" dataset:

```
hugeDS =
  AssociationMap[
   RandomReal[1, 1000] &,
   intToAlpha /@ Range[1000]
   ];
hugeDS // ByteCount

(* 9461936 *)
```

Then we export it as described in the previous link:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  $wdxFile =
    Export["~/Desktop/test.wdx",
     {
      "Keys" -> Keys@hugeDS,
      "Properties" -> {"Data"},
      "Data" ->
       Thread[List@Values@hugeDS]
      },
     "DataTable"
     ];
  ] // First

(* 8.85185 *)
```

This export time is why it pays to have a largely static dataset, as WDX is not built to be edited conveniently.

Then we build a WDX importer which will allow us to just access certain properties of it:

```
wdxImporter[wdx_] :=
 Module[{wdxRead, wdxIndex},
  ClearAttributes[{wdxRead, wdxIndex}, Temporary];
  wdxIndex =
   AssociationThread @@
    Lookup[
     Import[
      $wdxFile,
      {"WDX", "DataTable"}
      ],
     {"Keys", "Index"}
     ];
  wdxRead[Keys] :=
   Keys@wdxIndex;
  wdxRead[Values] :=
   wdxRead@Keys@wdxIndex;
  wdxRead[All] :=
   AssociationThread[wdxRead[Keys], wdxRead[Values]];
  wdxRead[bit_?(KeyMemberQ[wdxIndex, #] &), 
    keepOpen : True | False : False] :=

   With[{strm = OpenRead[wdx, BinaryFormat -> True]},
    SetStreamPosition[strm, wdxIndex[bit]];
    (
       If[Not@keepOpen, Close[strm]]; #
       ) &@System`Convert`WDXDump`readWDXObject@strm
    ];
  wdxRead[bits : {__?(KeyMemberQ[wdxIndex, #] &)}, 
    keepOpen : True | False : False] :=

   With[{strm = OpenRead[wdx, BinaryFormat -> True]},
    (
       If[Not@keepOpen, Close[strm]]; #
       ) &@
     Table[
      SetStreamPosition[strm, wdxIndex[b]];
      System`Convert`WDXDump`readWDXObject@strm,
      {b, bits}
      ]
    ];
  wdxRead
  ]
```

The trick here is that the WDX `"Index"` describes the [`StreamPosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPosition.html) where the element starts and the next byte describes what type it is and then the next bytes are the data. But `` System`Convert`WDXDump`readWDXObject `` handles the actual import. We just need to set the position.

This factory returns an import function which we can use to access elements from the stream:

```
read = wdxImporter[$wdxFile]
(* wdxRead$352020 *)

read["AAA"] // Length
(* 1000 *)
```

And notice that we actually gained some memory efficiency by using WDX:

```
$wdxFile // FileByteCount
(* 9022326 *)

hugeDS // ByteCount
(* 9461936 *)
```

And if you have lots of duplicate elements you'll gain even more, as WDX is configured to remove duplicates by default.